# Instagram logout is not working in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, instagram

I am integrated Instagram in iPhone,At first time login page display on my iPhone and after logout when again login than credentials are not Asking and directly login. i also 'nil' old credentials on logout and i also clear cookie at logout but it not working.when i delete cookie from safari then it work fine. how to solve it programetically.

Logout Button code as below

```
-(void)doLogout
 {
    IGAppDelegate* appDelegate = (IGAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];

// clear cookie

 NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
 NSArray* instagramCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://instagram.com/"]];

    NSLog(@"Array is == %@",instagramCookies);

    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in instagramCookies) 
    {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

// accessToken set nil

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"accessToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i am facing same issue ...if any solution then plz post it as an answer.

Comment: you open in safari then its store its credential, You have to open Instagram login URL in webview.

Answer (score 1):

We have to use WebView instead of safari so this problem will be solved.
I have made some changes in crino's sdk in which this problem has been resolved. 
You can get code from https://github.com/gouravgupta72/instagramIOSsdk/  here.